# GridView OnRowData Bound, Img_Data from SQL Base64string without templatefild

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, base64url

On my page i have a Gridview fildet over SQl Auto witout Template Filds.
All setting are code behind. ondatabound

Now i have a Base64 String in the sql table and gridview dont schow image.
i see the base64string in the result.

How i can convert the string to image in code behind
section witout TemplateFilds in aspx. Templatefild is not able Gridview is dinamicel over
multible combination of databases. Just the firs 2 columns are staic.

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="mergeresult" runat="server" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" OnRowCreated="mergeresult_OnRowCreated"
                                OnRowDataBound="mergeresult_OnRowDataBound" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" 
                                ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both" autogeneratedcolumns=false>
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Small" Font-Underline="true" />
                            <RowStyle Font-Size="12px" />

                         </asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
        protected void mergeresult_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
                int totalRow = mergeresult.Rows.Count;
                int totalColumns = mergeresult.Columns.Count;
 
           for (int i = 0; i < totalRow + 1; i++)
              {
                e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                // Image Converting ?? Field e.Row.Cells[1] have the base64 string inside.



              }
                 
         }
    }








             
}
```

DataBind

```
  protected void run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    { 
       // Dynamicel results from SQL Databases


        mergeresult.DataSource = dt1;
        mergeresult.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manipulate your SQL so the output is like below,  [How to display Base64 images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

```
 <div>
 <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
 <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @JobesK for your solution. I have solved my case using the following code:

```cs
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Length >= 500)
    {
        // string data = "";
        String TagStart1 = "";
        String Coding = "";
        String TagEnd = "";
        string Combi = "";
        String Dimension = "";
        string AltText = "";

        //data = cell.Text.ToString();
        TagStart1 = "<img src=";
        Coding = "data:image/jpg;base64,";
        TagEnd = "\"";
        Combi = TagStart1 + TagEnd + Coding + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + TagEnd;
        Dimension = " width=\"65px\" height=\"65px\">";
        AltText = " alt=\"testing\""; // "alt=\"" + e.Row.Cells[4].ToString() +"\"";
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = Combi + AltText + Dimension;
        e.Row.Cells[1].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Kein Bild";
    }
}
```

Do you know how to put the images in Original Format from base64 into a `<span high="75px" width="75px">` Tag with Format resizing.

Comment: you can try creating a cssclass then setting it e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "yourclass";